# Subversion error when opening project in vs2012 ultimate

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, visualsvn, ankhsvn

When I open the project, I am poping with an error message

```
" 
Subversion detected a working copy that needs an explicit upgrade in 'some directory'.

While this working copy is not upgraded all files in this working copy will appear as new.

When a working copy is upgraded it can no longer be used by Subversion clients that weren't designed for this (or later) working copy formats.

Further working copy upgraded required warnings are suppressed until after you restart Visual Studio."
```

How to fix this problem. I am using visual studio 2012 ultimate, subversion latest, and ankh latest version.

Comment: I am having this same error but do not have permission to upgrade programs on my work computer. Is there another way to fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ankh was recently upgraded to SVN 1.8 - probably your Tortoise or Command Line svn are not yet.
Update to the latest SVN version, and using that, upgrade your working copy to SVN 1.8 repo format. That'll make the message go away!

Comment: Installed Ankh per VS2012 recommendation. Upgraded Tortoise SVN to 1.8.0. Ta-da.

Comment: Very helpful. In my case, installing TortoiseSVN and then using it to upgrade the project directory to the 1.8 format worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It was a little bit longer for me. Here are the steps (assuming that Ankh updated to the latest version):

1. To avoid this error after the upgrade, do this in advance "svn:
   E155037: Cleanup with an older 1.7 client before upgrading with this
   client"
2. Uninstall slicksvn or other non-tortoise command line tools if you have one.
3. Update tortoise to the latest version (with command line tools). Check that command line svn is of the latest version with command "svn --version" in your working dir
4. Run "svn upgrade" in the root of your working dir

BTW, clean checkout is always an option when you start spending too much time on the upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, after this dialog each item in Solution Explorer was marked with "+" sign. I was using VS 2013 and ankhsvn 2.5.

Solution was to open VS menu VIEW -> Working Copy Explorer, right click on my solution in the left tree panel, click "Update to Latest Version". After that items in Solution Explorer were shown with proper svn state and that dialog did not appear anymore.

EDIT:

After this I've found that solution folder is no longer maintainable with TortoiseSVN 1.7 that I had, so finally I had to update it as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I could not update the `SVN` because it is maintained by the network administrator. So to solve, I got the version of `Ankhsvn` that is compatible with my SVN network.

The link below is possible to download the current version and the previous AnkSVN

https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/downloads

Answer (score 0):

From the solution Explorer Tab> Select your project > right Clic> Upgrade solution.
This works for me on Visual Studio 2017 and Tortoise Svn 1.17.